# If Covid antibodies disappear after 2-3 months, will a vaccine still be effective?

Tags: pathology, coronavirus, vaccination

It looks like there have been studies in [China](https://www.businessinsider.com/coronavirus-antibodies-only-last-months-weaker-in-asymptomatic-cases-2020-6) and also in [Spain](https://www.businessinsider.com/coronavirus-antibodies-study-herd-immunity-unachievable-spain-2020-7) that suggest antibodies don't last very long or could disappear after some time. What does this mean for the effectiveness of a potential vaccine? Could the effects wear off after a few months? Is this different from other diseases we get vaccinated for? I know we need to update the flu vaccine every year, but I thought that was due to mutations in the virus, not from antibodies breaking down. I am not a scientist, can anyone ELI5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humans don't constantly produce antibodies for a pathogen when the pathogen has been gone for a while. They just store the 'recipe' for making the particular antibody in memory T cells.

If the antigens that the virus contains mutate enough to not work for the antibodies an immune person has developed. Then the process starts over and the immune system will have to 'create a new recipe'.

Each new host creates a possible scenario for a coronavirus such as the current [SARS-CoV-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severe_acute_respiratory_syndrome_coronavirus_2) to [mutate](https://www.centerforhealthsecurity.org/resources/COVID-19/COVID-19-fact-sheets/200128-nCoV-whitepaper.pdf) and develop different antigens that may cause a second wave requiring humans to develop new antibodies in our immune system and new vaccines to be distributed.

Though coronaviruses do not mutate as quickly as other viruses such as the [influenza virus](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/137129/matpau_1.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y). It is still possible that SARS-CoV-2 having caused such a large pandemic, may develop a new strain.

Comment: As far as I have followed the papers, the genetic stability of SARS-CoV-2 seems pretty high. Can you please add some ressources to back your claim?

Comment: Thank you! This is so helpful. So vaccines help create memory T cells. But why would normal antibodies not be stored in T cells? Are they only activated when there are a certain number or strength of virus?

Comment: When a recognized virus has been detected by the immune system, the memory T-cells multiply into more memory T-cells as well as plasma B cells which are able to actually use the 'recipe' to produce antibodies that flow freely in the blood and neutralize their target antigen. For each immunity you have developed, you have specific memory T-cells that store the 'recipe' for that one antigen. eventually over a long amount of time these memory T-cells may die which is why people need to take a tetanus vaccine around every 10 years (as an example)